# Help with understanding a proof concerning traces of a Galois extension

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, trace

Let $K$ be a field, $L$ a galois extension of $K$ and $M$ a galois extension of $K$, with $K \subseteq M \subseteq L$. Define the trace of an element $a \in L$ as follows: $$tr_{L/K}(a) := \sum_{\sigma \in Gal(L/K)} \sigma(a).$$ I'm reading a proof of the fact that $\forall a \in M$: $$tr_{L/K}(a) = [L:M]tr_{M/K}(a),$$ and there's one step where I don't understand the reasoing. The proof starts like this: because of the galois correspondence, there exists a group morphism $$\varphi: Gal(L/K) \rightarrow Gal(M/K): \sigma \mapsto \sigma{|_M}.$$ Let $a \in M.$ Then, \begin{eqnarray*}
tr_{L/K}(a) &=& \sum_{\sigma \in Gal(L/K)} \sigma(a) = \sum_{\sigma \in Gal(L/K)} \sigma_{|_M}(a) \\
&=&\sum_{\sigma' \in Gal(M/K)} [L:M] \cdot \sigma'(a).
\end{eqnarray*}
Then, the proof continues. However, I'm having problems with understanding the last step: $\sum_{\sigma \in Gal(L/K)} \sigma_{|_M}(a) =\sum_{\sigma' \in Gal(M/K)} [L:M] \cdot \sigma'(a).$ I searched the internet, but all the other proofs are based on composition maps or other stuff like that and it looks like the writer didn't use that. Can anyone please explain this to me?

As always, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Each automorphism on $M$ fixing $K$ arises from the same number of automorphisms of $L$, namely $[L:M]$ of them. Do you understand the restriction map on Galois groups $\sigma \mapsto \sigma|_M$?

Comment: What do you mean about other proofs being based on stuff like "composition" maps? I do not know what the term composition map means.

Comment: They all use that $tr_{L/K} = tr_{M/K} \circ tr_{L/M}$. And I now realise that the writer also used  that. But I'm afraid I still don't see it.

Comment: Oooooooooooooooh, I see it now (I think)! If you could post your comment a bit more detailed as an answer, I'll be happy to accept it!

Comment: That property is called *transitivity* of the trace map, not composition.  But I understand what you mean by it now.

Comment: The trace map can be defined for any finite extension of fields, not just Galois extensions.  See http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/galoistheory/tracenorm.pdf and http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/galoistheory/tracenorm2.pdf (the second file discusses the link to the formula you use in the case of a Galois extension.